# StreamProvider pass values and update the stream result

Tags: flutter, dart, provider

I am trying to pass a variable to the `StreamProvider` put once the app loads changing `endTime` values doesn't change the Stream output/data.

```
class _PrayersGlobalState extends State<PrayersGlobal> {
  PrayersViewModel modelGlobal = serviceLocator<PrayersViewModel>();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    modelGlobal.streamData(
      prayerType: 1,
      userId: 1,
      updatedOn: '2020-04-10',
      endTime: '2020-05-' + ((1 + _random.nextInt(5)) * 5).toString(),
    );
    return MultiProvider(
      providers: [
        StreamProvider<List<Prayers>>(
          create: (context) => modelGlobal.streamPrayers,
          catchError: (context, err) {
            print('Error : ' + err.toString());
            return;
          },
        ),
      ],
```

Here is the **streamData** function it getting a stream from a GraphQL subscription

```
void streamData({
    int prayerType,
    int userId,
    String updatedOn,
    String endTime,
  }) {
    final Stream<Prayers> streamPs = _graphQLService.getPrayerStream(
      prayerType: prayerType,
      userId: userId,
      updatedOn: updatedOn,
      endTime: endTime,
    );
    print('EndTime In Model : $endTime');
    this._streamPrayers.sink.addStream(streamPs);
  }
```

Comment: Mind to post what your `streamData` method is doing?

Comment: its's making a call to GraphQL query and returns the data, it work the first time the app loads after that changing the value of `endTime` doesn't seems to effect the output of the stream

Comment: I've updated the code.

Answer (score 1):

This code was working 100% correctly I was using a flutter package called `hasura_connect`

https://pub.dev/packages/hasura_connect

I missed reading the documentation properly there is a separate function that needs to be called to pass different values to the variable.

```
//change values of variables for PAGINATIONS
snapshot.changeVariable({"limit": 20});
```